# get new entered DataGridView cell value using c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to get the new cell value of a `DataGridView` when the cell was null before. I'm using C# and this code:

```
private void gridViewTimes_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
}
```

This works fine when the cell value was not null before. But if the cell was null before it throws the exception

Exception:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.

I'm a bit confused about this because when I leave the cell I wrote something in the cell so it isn't null anymore. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Any suggestions?

Comment: check if the `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value` is not null first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the value is not null before assigning:

```
private void gridViewTimes_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value != null)
    {
        string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple but genius. Why didn't I get that for myself? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

`CellLeave` event is fring before value is actually changes. Use `CellValueChanged` event.

Comment: The problem is, when I use `CellValueChanged` it is fired by `Form_Load()` because I add rows to the `DataGridView` on `Form_Load()` event.

Comment: Yes, that's a problem. Check if the value is null. See the other answer below, it explains how to check if value is null.